# Lodash - Select elements that are not in the array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array:

```
[
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4
  }
]
```

Every 5 seconds my application receives a new array and I need to compare the difference between the next one...

So the next array is:

```
[
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4
  }
]
```

How can I compare with the previous and get an array with the excluded item?

```
[
  {
    id: 3
  }
]
```

---

### Right question

[Lodash - DifferenceBy with different identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219162/lodash-differenceby-with-different-identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Lodash `differenceBy` method and pass `id` prop if you want to find difference based on `id`. Otherwise you can use `_.differenceWith(prev, next, _.isEqual)`

```js
const prev = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]
const next = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":4}]

const diff = _.differenceBy(prev, next, 'id')
console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

In case you want to check for different keys or id prop names you can use `differenceWith` and pass custom equality check function.

```js
const prev = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]
const next = [{"contact_id":1},{"contact_id":2},{"contact_id":4}]

const checkId = (prev, next) => {
  return prev.id == next.contact_id
}

const diff = _.differenceWith(prev, next, checkId)
console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: And if `const next = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":4}]` is `const next = [{"contact_id":1},{"contact_id":2},{"contact_id":4}]`?

Comment: @Caio Kawasaki See update.